# Named arrays, dataframes and matrices

Tags: r

If I split my data matrix into rows according to class labels in another vector `y` like this, the result is something with 'names' like this:

```
> X <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),nrow=4,ncol=2)
> y <- c(1,3,1,3)
> X_split <- split(as.data.frame(X),y)
$`1`
  V1 V2
1  1  5
3  3  7

$`3`
  V1 V2
2  2  6
4  4  8
```

I want to loop through the results and do some operations on each matrix, for example sum the elements or sum the columns. How do I access each matrix in a loop so I can that?

```
labels = names(X_split)
for (k in labels) {
    # How do I get X_split[k] as a matrix?
    sum_class = sum(X_split[k]) # Doesn't work
}
```

In fact, I don't really want to deal with dataframes and named arrays at all. Is there a way I can call `split` without `as.data.frame` and get a list of matrices or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To split without converting to a data frame

```
X_split <- list(X[c(1, 3), ], X[c(2, 4), ])
```

More generally, to write it in terms of a vector `y` of length `nrow(X)`, indicating the group to which each row belongs, you can write this as

```
X_split <- lapply(unique(y), function(i) X[y == i, ])
```

To sum the results

```
X_sum <- lapply(X_split, sum)

# [[1]]
# [1] 16

# [[2]]
# [1] 20
```

(or use `sapply` if you want the result as a vector)

Comment: How would I write that in terms of my `y`?

Comment: `lapply(unique(y), function(i) X[y == i, ])` would loop through the array several times (once for each unique `y`) instead of once though wouldn't it?

Comment: It iteraters over `unique(y)` (in this case `c(1,3)`) not `X` so it doesn't go through the array at all. But it will return copies of each sub-indexed part of `X`, if that's what you are asking (just as split does).

Comment: What I mean is each call to `X[y == i, ]` requires a separate pass through `y` to find the matching indices which seems redundant since the split could be done in a single loop over `y`.

Comment: That's true, but why is it a problem? This would only be an issue if your matrix `X` was very large, in which case the real bottleneck would be creating the copies and not the `y==i` part (and if you have a large matrix you shouldn't be using `split` anyway, `data.table` which has already been mentioned is much more efficient)

Comment: @Andrew To avoid repeatedly constructing logical vectors (like `y==i` for each `i`), use `X_split <- lapply(split(1:nrow(X),y),function(rs)X[rs,])`. (Feel free to edit this into the answer.)

Answer (score 3):

Another option is not to split in the first place and just sum per `y`. Here's a possible `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(X)[, sum(sapply(.SD, sum)), by = y]
#    y V1
# 1: 1 16
# 2: 3 20
```

Comment: I need to do other operations on each matrix than just sum (I have edited the question sorry). Basically I just want to extract the matrix as a matrix in each iteration of the loop, but I can't work out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure operating directly on the matrix is most efficient:

```
tapply(rowSums(X),y,sum)
#  1  3 
# 16 20
```