# how to split an array into separate arrays (R)?

Tags: arrays, r

I have the array:

```
>cent
       b    e          r    f
A19 60.46   0.77    -0.12   1
A15 16.50   0.53    0.08    2
A17 2.66    0.51    0.20    3
A11 36.66   0.40    -0.25   4
A12 38.96   0.91    0.23    1
A05 0.00    0.29    0.01    2
A09 3.40    0.35    0.03    3
A04 0.00    0.25    -0.03   4
```

Could some one please say me how to split this array into 4 separate arrays where the last column «f» is the flag? In result I would like to see:

```
>cent1
       b    e          r    f
A19 60.46   0.77    -0.12   1
A12 38.96   0.91    0.23    1
>cent2
       b    e          r    f
A15 16.50   0.53    0.08    2
A05 0.00    0.29    0.01    2
….
```

Should I use the for-loop and check flag "f" or exist a build-in function? Thanks.

Comment: If it's really an array, and not a data frame, then try [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30122693/named-arrays-dataframes-and-matrices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `split` to create a `list` of `data.frames`.

```
 lst <- split(cent, cent$f)
```

NOTE: Here I assumed that the 'cent' is a data.frame.  If it is a `matrix`

```
 lst <- split(as.data.frame(cent), cent[,"f"])
```

Usually, it is enough to do most of the analysis.  But, if we need to create multiple objects in the global environment, we can use `list2env` (not recommended)

```
 list2env(lst, paste0("cent", seq_along(lst)), envir= .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: thanks you for reply. The function split() is work. Now I have the list lst. How can I address to elements in the list lst[1] that are of the same type, say $b?

Comment: I have tried lst[1]$b, lst['1'], lst[1]$'1'. But I need to extract first column only.

Comment: @Nick If you need the first column `lst[[1]][1]` (if the dataset is data.frame) , if is is matrix `lst[[1]][,1]`